# Selenium find element that just appeared

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Currently, I have a code that web scrapes a live chat.
The live chat can be 1000 messages long but I want to print every new message that appears.
Right now when I find a comment in the live chat, I check I already found that one using a list. But after some time the list becomes too long and the code will lag.

**Is there a way to find the newest appearing element on screen without getting the old ones?**

**Code:**

```
full_comments = main.find_elements_by_xpath('messageid')
for full_comment in full_comments:
    if full_comment not in used_comment:
        comment = full_comment.find_element_by_css_selector('comment').text
        print(comment)     
        used_comment.append(full_comment)
```

**Website:**

```
<div messageid>
     <comment>
<div messageid>
     <comment>
<div messageid>
     <comment>
<div messageid>
     <comment>
```

So when there is a new element with messageid, I only want to fetch the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a more complex XPath selector.  You can find W3Schools' documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp.

I'm no HTML expert, but I think you should be able to do:

```
//comment[position() > last() - 5]
```

To get the last 5 messages, then compare only those.